# Translate GNU ps flags to standard flags

Tags: osx, ps, gnu, ssh-agent, oh-my-zsh

I'm using `oh-my-zsh` and its `ssh-agent` plugin on OSX, but lately somebody upstream decided to use `ps x`. I'm not entirely sure what that even does, since I haven't used a GNU userland in something close to a decade. The goal appears to be finding out whether `ssh-agent` is already running, so I'm not sure why any flags to `ps` are even needed. Can somebody help me cook up a cross-platform-friendly alternative?

UPDATE: If you want to take a look for yourself, here's [the source for the `ssh-agent` plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/ssh-agent/ssh-agent.plugin.zsh)

Comment: There is no GNU `ps`. `ps x` is BSD syntax, so I'd expect it to work on OS/X

Comment: `ps -e` if you want anything cross-platform

Comment: @StephaneChazelas `ps x` might be BSD syntax, but it's not a valid flag to `ps`. [man ps](http://man.cx/ps) On the other hand, it *does* seem to valid on Linux ([a Linux distro's man ps](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps)). Since Linux distros use the GNU userland, I assumed it was a GNU thing.

Comment: Linux distributions use a GNU userland, but `ps` is one of the tools that are very kernel-specific and is part of util-linux, not GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, the main effect of `ps x` is to include all processes running as the same user. By default, `ps` only includes processes running on the same terminal. In contrast, the BSD default is to include processes that have a controlling terminal, whether it's the same or not. The corresponding BSD option is `-x`. In addition, `ps x` selects a slightly different output format. The [POSIX syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/ps.html) to match the same processes is

```
ps -A -u "$USER"
```

If you're parsing the output of `ps` be sure to use the `-o` flag to control which columns are printed. Note that the commands in my answer don't print exactly the same columns.

To look for an ssh-agent process, you do need to pass some options, since both Linux and BSD hide processes that aren't associated to any terminal by default, and it's common for ssh-agent not to be associated with a terminal.

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]; then
  SSH_AGENT_PID=$(ps -A -u "$USER" -o comm= | grep ssh-agent | head -n 1)
fi
if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]; then
  …
```

Comment: Am I misreading the various man pages, or is there no one combination of flags that will work on OS X, BSD, and Linux?

Comment: @HankGay My code snippet should work on all modern unices. I added a link to the standard.

Comment: On FreeBSD, I needed to switch it to `-U` instead of `-u`. On OpenBSD it doesn't have `-A`. I am rather sad that my beloved BSDs aren't obeying the standard.